# Are APA Hotels in Japan a good choice for budget travel?

Tags: japan, hotels, tokyo

I am planning on travelling around Japan for 2 weeks in May, starting off in Tokyo then riding the Shinkansen to Kyoto, Osaka and Hiroshima.

Whilst looking at hotels in Tokyo I have noticed the APA chain is particularly affordable, circa £60 - £80 a night and good star ratings.

The photos of the hotel look very decent (obviously photos should be taken with a pinch of salt - hence the question).

Has anyone stayed in APA hotels whilst in Japan with experiences they can share, are they a decent place to stay when on a budget?

Note; I am looking for hotels that are functional (bed and private shower will do) and clean/hygienic

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: There must surely be some guest reviews out there eg TripAdviser

Comment: @Traveller Or on booking.com?

Comment: The APA chain is owned by a notorious right-wing activist who denies the Nanking massacre and until recently placed books saying so in the rooms, so I personally avoid them for that reason alone: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/19/business/japan-china-motoya-hotel-apa.html

Comment: @Joe though as long as he keeps the peace, he has as much right to make a living as anyone else.

Comment: @RobertColumbia He does indeed, The public, however, may take its trade elsewhere as a demonstration of its dislike of his views.

Comment: APA, Toyoko, Super Hotel and a couple of others are large chains of business hotels in Japan where you simply can’t go wrong. You know one, you know them all.

Answer (score 3):

I stayed in 2 different APA hotels in the last month (in Hiroshima and Tokyo) and they meet your requirements (bed, private toilet & shower) and are quite nice, but that is a matter of opinion.